# How do I set the tab stops to 2 spaces in CEdit?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, tabstop, cedit

The `CEdit::SetTabStops` method is confusing me a little.

All I want to do is set the tab stops every 2 characters, or atleast a quart of what it is right now.

How do I do that with this method?

Comment: There is a reasonable [example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ceditview-class?view=msvc-170#settabstops) given for the equivalent in the `CEditView` class.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for that link. I now noticed that here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=msvc-170#settabstops) it said that there was a sample (which you referred to). Their sample is bugged though because`SetTabStops` is not prefixed by the edit control ... but I have it working now. Much appreciated.

Comment: I think that sample code is intended to part of a member function of a `CEditView` derived class ... so it doesn't need the explicit control reference. I thought about posting an answer, but I'd be doing very little other than copying published code.

Comment: @AdrianMole That’s ok. The link is sufficient. Just wish I could resolve my other question with drag n drop and cursor caret.